# Fluent NHibernate - override table names

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

Application has many extension assemblies and they contain mappings for their classes. I need to add prefix to all (base, join, many-to-many, ...) table names in those mappings.

E.g.

```
Assembly:        ~/bin/Extensions/Foo.dll
Original table:  Page
New table:       Ext_Foo_Page

Assembly:        ~/bin/Extensions/Bar.dll
Original table:  Page
New table:       Ext_Bar_Page
```

What's the most straightforward way to do that?

I tried this

```
public class TableNameConvention : IClassConvention, IJoinedSubclassConvention, IHasManyToManyConvention
{
    private string getPrefix()
    {
        return "Ext_Test_";
    }
    public void Apply(FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Instances.IClassInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Table(getPrefix() + instance.TableName);
    }

    public void Apply(FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Instances.IJoinedSubclassInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Table(getPrefix() + instance.TableName);
    }
    public void Apply(FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Instances.IManyToManyCollectionInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Table(getPrefix() + instance.TableName);
    }
}
```

but it doesn't change table names even though those methods are executed.

EDIT - The configuration

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
var sw = new StringWriter(sb);

var cfg = Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(b => b.Server(@".\SQLEXPRESS").Database("test123").Username("sa").Password("...")))
    .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(assembly).Conventions.Add<TableNameConvention>().ExportTo(sw))
    .ExposeConfiguration(c => { new SchemaUpdate(c).Execute(false, true); })
    .BuildSessionFactory();

var xml = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: which Version of FNH do you use? Does it call the convention for the classes in Foo.dll and Bar.dll (see instance.Type)?

Comment: FNH version is 1.2.0.712 and convention gets called for all class mappings, but table names stay the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with FNH 1.2.0.712

it works with

```
var model = new PersistenceModel();
model.Add(typeof(EntityMap));
model.Conventions.Add<TableNameConvention>();
model.WriteMappingsTo(Console.Out);
```

but not with

```
m.FluentMappings.Add(typeof(EntityMap)).Conventions.Add<TableNameConvention>().ExportTo(Console.Out)
```

it's not called in the second example, maybe bug. but the following works

```
.Mappings(m => 
{
    m.AutoMappings.Add(() => new AutoPersistenceModel().Conventions.Add<TableNameConvention>());
    m.FluentMappings.Add(typeof(EntityMap)).ExportTo(Console.Out);
})
```

Comment: Using the first sample, it only overrides table names if they are not defined in the classmap. If there's `Table("tablename");` in the mapping, then it doesn't override. Using the last sample it first writes the mappings to the console and after that calls that convention. I guess for some reason FNH does things in wrong order.

Comment: values are used like: mapping ?? convention ?? default. so tablenames in mappings are always prefered to conventions. you have to use override or set them with `config.GetClassMappings()`

Comment: Maybe I'll just make extensions provide mappings as XmlDocuments and use plain `NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddDocument(XmlDocument doc)`

Comment: or just after adding the fluent mappings do `config.GetClassMappings().Where(m => IsExtension(m.Type.Assembly)).ForEach(m => m.Table.Name = "ext_" + m.Table.Name)`

Answer (score 0):

The following syntax works for me:

```
return Fluently.Configure()
               .Database(...)
               .Mappings(m =>
                    {
                        m.AutoMappings.Add(
                            AutoMap.AssemblyOf<EntityMap>(new ImporterAutomappingConfiguration())
                                   .Conventions.Add<TableNameConvention>());
                    })
                .BuildSessionFactory();
```